# How to call javascript array of methods having callbacks to run sequentially?

Tags: javascript, callback, sequential

I have the following methods to be called sequentially. 
Note that timeout is differing so by default it will run based on timeout.

```
function asyncTask1(done) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('task 1 done');
    done(1);
  }, 500);
}
function asyncTask2(done) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('task 2 done');
    done(2);
  }, 400);
}
function asyncTask3(done) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('task 3 done');
    done(3);
  }, 300);
}

function sequential(tasks = []) {

}
 sequential(tasks);
```

Comment: Have you tried something? Did you have a look at promises, or async.js?

Comment: Thanks @Bergi for answering I was looking for solution without using any library or Promises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it recursively:

```
function sequential([first, ...last], done) {
  if (!first) done();
  else first(() => sequential(last, done);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @torazaburo.

Answer (score 0):

This was a very useful reply, but took me a bit of time to put it all together. Here is the function in use

```
function done() {
    console.log("DONE")
} 

var callbacks = [
    function callback1(next) {
        console.log("callback1")
        next()
    },
    function callback2(next) {
        console.log("callback2")
        next()
    },
    function callback3(next) {
        console.log("callback3")
        next()
    },
    function callback4(next) {
        console.log("callback4")
        next()
    },
    function callback5(next) {
        console.log("callback5")
        next()
    }
]

function sequential([first, ...last], done) {   
    if (!first) 
        done();
    else
        first(() => {sequential(last,done);})
}

//And call it. 
sequential(callbacks, done);
```